# How to detect any modal window on site Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I make script which open site from text document (in document it about 150+ sites) and make screenshot of first screen. I have two problems. It is cookie alert and modal popup windows like "subscribe on our newsletter", "10% discount on this weekend" and something like this. Cookie alert was handeled by add crx extension before  driver launch ( Pop up blocker for Chrome™ - Poper Blocker). But i not found something like this for modal windows. All modal windows have different xPath and class names. Like "modal", "ui-diaglod", "popup", etc. I have a question how to handle modals and dimming the background and after closing them make screenshot. I tried handle it by adding JavaScript script that searching  modals by class names, but it so many classes that my solution didn`t work properly